# Deploying issue with MVC application with Telerik Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, deployment, telerik

I am a noob at deploying mvc code. Basically i have a windows server 2008 instance that i setup to host a MVC3 website that uses mvc telerik extensions. The website loads perfectly fine in my local dev box, but once it is deployed it loses all the jquery and styling it seems, also my database connection does not appear to be working because there is no data populated in the poorly rendered grids for my views. the website is located here: WebSite. This page is a view that has a tabstrip that have links to partial views. When the page loads you will see that when you click on a tab it does not render like the attached image displays.  I have checked to make sure that the style sheets and telerik dlls are included in the deployment when the website is deployed to IIS.  Also you will notice that there is no data in the grids. This confuses me because I used the same connection string in the debug.config except I placed the underlying SQL connection string in there in this format:

```
<add name="PayRentEntities" `connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PayRent.csdl|res://*/Models.PayRent.ssdl|res://*/Models.PayRent.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data Source=SQL001; Initial Catalog=PayRent; User ID=****; Password=******!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>`
```

Also you will notice that when you click on the tabs the address changes at the top which means it is not loading the partial view within the parent view. In the VS on my local machine the content loads nicely within the main Admin View. Here is the code for the Apartment View to be loaded within the Admin Tabstrip view

```
parent.Add()
    .Text("Apartments")
    .LoadContentFrom("ApartmentGridOnDemand", "Apartment");
```

Comment: You forgot the link to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the database connection. I ended up debugging my web site with FireBug for FireFox. This allowed me to find out that there were several internal server errors which appeared to be missing files and wrong path names that broke during deploying of the code. I was able to resolve these by making sure the files were there and that the path names were corrected on the master page to those files (script, css files).  The website works fine now.